# why edges of textfield Get Clipped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Edges of UITextfield get Clipped form all the corners when i set corner radious property.
does anybody knows why this happening?
thanks!!!

my Code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
     fullNameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = fullNameTextField.frame.size.height / 2
    }
```

result:
[image]

i want to achieve this:[image]

Comment: try to add `fullNameTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true`

Comment: tried but dont work :( @Tj3n

Comment: Give a `borderwidth` and `bordercolor` and then set the `cornerRadius` and `clipsToBounds` and then see if the issues is solved. @UdayBabariya

Comment: `fullNameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0` , `fullNameTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrey` , `fullNameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = fullNameTextField.frame.size.height / 2` , `fullNameTextField.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Set you borderStyle "none" and then provide border width and corner radius to the textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your border style to none and draw your border using in layer:

```
    fullNameTextField.borderStyle = .none
    fullNameTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    fullNameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    fullNameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = fullNameTextField.frame.size.height / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

yes buddy its because your text field contains boder style. in interface builder select your text field and choose rounded boder style if you need border.. attaching an image have a look and you can fix it from storyboard :)

[image: here is the image]